# Rounding NSDecimalNumber

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, rounding

I'm having the hardest time figuring out something that seems like it should be very simple. I need to accurately round an NSDecimalNumber to a particular number of decimal places (determined at runtime.) So far as I can tell, I have two options, neither of which I like.

1. **Convert to a float, and use C rounding functions:** I don't like this because accuracy matters in this case. Floats can't always accurately represent decimal numbers, and this could cause problems.
2. **Convert to a string using NSNumberFormatter and then convert back:** I don't like this one because it just seems ugly and inefficient.

Is there another way that I've missed? There has *got* to be an easy way to do rounding of NSDecimalNumbers, but I can't seem to figure out for the life of me what it is.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You simply call `decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:`with the desired `NSDecimalNumberBehaviors` protocol. See the `NSDecimalNumberBehaviors` reference in the [dev docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSDecimalNumberBehaviors_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSDecimalNumberBehaviors).

Update: See http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/23/cocoa-tutorial-dont-be-lazy-with-nsdecimalnumber-like-me/

Comment: RTFM was not the response. The response was "You simply call decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:with the desired NSDecimalNumberBehaviors protocol." The dev docs were referenced to provide the enumeration of the various protocols rather than copying them here.

Answer (score 24):

For those that prefer example code...

To round to 2 decimal places (12345.68):

```
NSDecimalNumber *originalNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"12345.6789"];
NSDecimalNumberHandler *behavior = [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundPlain
                                                                                          scale:2
                                                                               raiseOnExactness:NO
                                                                                raiseOnOverflow:NO
                                                                               raiseOnUnderflow:NO
                                                                            raiseOnDivideByZero:NO];

NSDecimalNumber *roundedNumber = [originalNumber decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:behavior];
```

To round to the nearest thousand (12000):

```
NSDecimalNumber *originalNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"12345.6789"];
NSDecimalNumberHandler *behavior = [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundPlain
                                                                                          scale:-3
                                                                               raiseOnExactness:NO
                                                                                raiseOnOverflow:NO
                                                                               raiseOnUnderflow:NO
                                                                            raiseOnDivideByZero:NO];

NSDecimalNumber *roundedNumber = [originalNumber decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:behavior];
```

Answer (score 10):

I got it working using the below code in Swift 3.

```
let amount = NSDecimalNumber(string: "123.456789")
let handler = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .plain, scale: 2, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: false)
let roundedAmount = amount.rounding(accordingToBehavior: handler)
```

Note the scale parameter, used to define the decimal places you need. Outlined here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdecimalnumberhandler/1578295-decimalnumberhandlerwithrounding

Comment: this must be marked as accepted answer, works like a charm and also allows us not to write any wheel-invention code (guess we all need to round price in SKProduct, otherwise who else needs this NSDecimalNumber)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this solution:

```
import Foundation

extension NSDecimalNumber {
    public func round(_ decimals:Int) -> NSDecimalNumber {
        return self.rounding(accordingToBehavior:
            NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .plain,
                                   scale: Int16(decimals),
                                   raiseOnExactness: false,
                                   raiseOnOverflow: false,
                                   raiseOnUnderflow: false,
                                   raiseOnDivideByZero: false))
    }
}

let amount = NSDecimalNumber(string: "123.456")

amount.round(2)  --> 123.46
amount.round(1)  --> 123.5
amount.round(0)  --> 123
amount.round(-1) --> 120
amount.round(-2) --> 100
```