# NSNumberFormatter IOS Calculator display

Tags: ios, calculator, nsnumberformatter

Please somebody, help me. I am making Calculator App, and I used NSNumberFormatter . I want to set the limit of numbers showing at my UILabel, for example, maximum 12 digits, but it means , any digits even if "1234121.38685  (12)". So if I  multiply this number, it is being increasing and it must be rounded correctly, and I want it to be for example, "9785123124.12", if again, then "75647689751.5". So that the result-value showed maximum of integer part, not of float. How to make it ?

```
numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@" "];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSize:3];
[numberFormatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
[numberFormatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:10];
[numberFormatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];
[numberFormatter setMaximumIntegerDigits:10];
```

Comment: I'd suggest NSDecimalNumber has the functionality you're looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981219/rounding-nsdecimalnumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Adam Behringer ,
it is much more better to use this code for getting RoundMode correct !!

```
result=[[self math] calculations]; 
resultString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.16f", result];
 getIntPartOfValue=result; 
stringForGetIntPartOfValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld",getIntPartOfValue];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:(maximumAmountOfDigits stringForGetIntPartOfValue.length)+1];
```

Answer (score 0):

One was it convert the number to a NSString using the number formatter that you have set up. Make sure that the total digits will be more than 10. Then use the string class to truncate the number.

```
NSString *numbLong = @"123023.123781237912378123"; // get this from your number formatter
NSString *numbTruncated = [numbLong substringToIndex:10]; // 123023.123
```

Comment: Adam, it is good idea, but how to make this number also rounded ? From  your example I want to get  "123023.124"